# Add review queues to Android app

Tags: feature-request, review, android-app

I know there are some similar posts on adding review queues to the mobile web page. However, this is regarding the Stack Exchange Android app. I really would like to review posts and edits from the Android app, however this isn't included in the app yet. I'm not sure how it would be implemented; maybe there could be a button or something for review. Could we please see this?

Comment: This also assumes that Stack Exchange would be alright with implementing API calls to fetch review items and accept responses for those items. Honestly, that sounds a bit sketchy.

Comment: @animuson A dev whitelist?

Comment: How about also add review queues to iOS SE/SO app?

Comment: The Android app is no longer being maintained. See: [How can I report bugs with or request features for the Stack Exchange mobile apps?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/348075/how-can-i-report-bugs-with-or-request-features-for-the-stack-exchange-mobile-app)