# Are review queues available from the Android app?

Tags: support, review, android-app

The Winter Bash has inspired me to try out the Stack Exchange app for Android phones. I can see there are pull-out panes on the left and right for site navigation and notifications, respectively; on the top are achievements, search and new question. Is there a way to access review queues as well?

Comment: Related: [Add review queues to Android app](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215841/254929) feature request.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No. The review queues are only available from the full site. The mobile site is not optimized for the review queues and the mobile apps both rely on the API which [does not [currently] allow access to the review queues](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app).