# Moderator tools for Stack Exchange app

Tags: feature-request, review, android-app, 10k-tools, moderator-abilities

I would love to have the review and [moderator tools](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) from the website inside the app so that we can review low quality posts, edits and delete requests while we are having some free time when commuting to work or during classes or w/e.

Comment: Note that [there is an existing feature request for review tools](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/215841/254929).