# Add Review Queues to iOS app

Tags: feature-request, review, ios-app, mobile-web

In line with this question, [Add review queues to Android app](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215841/add-review-queues-to-android-app) review queues should be added to the iOS app. Currently, they can only be accessed from a mobile web browser, where the editing and flagging interface can be hard to interact with.

So why not add Review Queues to the iOS app. If not then at least make the web browser on mobile devices more optimised.

Comment: It is worth mentioning that the apps rely on the [Stack API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs) and there is no support in the API for review.